# How to save all intermediate files when building Android?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to save all intermediate files (C/C++ files after preprocessing, the .i and .ii) when building Android (compiling the source), but don't know how.

Anybody got some idea?

Comment: What do you mean intermediate?

Comment: @Yury I mean files after preprocessing.

Comment: You can read about ccache. Maybe this is what are you looking for.

Comment: @Yury I found a tool called GAST - Gcc Automatically Save Temps. I will look for ccache after some experiments using GAST. Thank you.

Comment: @Yury Failed to use GAST. I've looked for ccache, but the cached files are encoded and I cannot find the real preprocessed file. This is the new problem.

Comment: Meanwhile, have you considered the answer of @bjarkef?

Comment: Yes, but I only found .a/.o/.so and .jar in the `out` folder.

Comment: I've wrote a shell script using `inotify` and it seems effective. The compiling is still in progress, hope it will succeed this time.

Comment: I believe the preprocessed files are generated as such at all, I think gcc/g++ is invoked to directly generate the object file from the source, without producing preprocessed files on the filesystem in between.

Comment: I agree with you. gcc/g++ save preprocessed files only with -save-temps option. I've done the job with ccache+inotify, though it's a little bit troublesome and awkward.

Comment: Maybe I can change the makefile, to add `-save-temps` to some options such as `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty easy, all intermediate files are put in the `out` folder, which is created when you build. Just copy the `out` folder somewhere else to save all the intermediate files.

I do this quite frequently when I have to build for different targets (e.g. product and sdk build, which will clean each others intermediate files). By e.g. just copying `out` to `out-sdk`, and then I can copy it back when I have to do another sdk build later. Saves quite a bit of time.

Comment: I didn't express so well. I want all preprocessed files of .c and .cc, but only .o, .so and .a in the out folder. But thank you for answering @bjarkef.